# How to script a check that the key in known_hosts file is correct

Tags: ssh, scripting

I would like to implement a function in a script that checks if the key that corresponds to a given host in known_hosts file is correct. The obvious way to do this is to attempt an ssh connection and parse if it results in the known_hosts warning. This is suboptimal for these reasons:

- If the host is *not* in the know_hosts file it needs to be checked separately
- It relies on a particular wording of the warning that is subject to change
- It runs an ssh command for you on the target server that you do not need to run and which could fail for different reasons such as what login shell is specified
- Requires valid credentials

I tried to find an option in `ssh-keyscan` and `ssh-keygen` commands that might to that check, but did not find them.

What is the simplest way to do this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HOST=$1

set -o pipefail

HOST_KEY_LINE=$(ssh-keygen -F "$HOST" | tail -n1)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "$HOST is not in the known_hosts file"
  exit 1
fi

KEY_TYPE=$(echo "$HOST_KEY_LINE" | awk '{ print $2 }')
HOST_KEY=$(echo "$HOST_KEY_LINE" | awk '{ print $3 }')

ACTUAL_KEY=$(ssh-keyscan -t "$KEY_TYPE" "$HOST" 2>&1 | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $3 }')

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Could not get key from $HOST: $ACTUAL_KEY"
  exit 1
fi

if [ "$HOST_KEY" = "$ACTUAL_KEY" ]; then
  echo "known_hosts has a correct key"
  exit 0
fi

echo "known_hosts has an incorrect key"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of all hosts available you can use the below:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa -f hosts_list > ~/.ssh/known_hosts_revised
```

This will generate a new `known_hosts_revised` which you can use to make a diff with current `know_hosts` to see the differences.

The `hosts_list` content should be like:

```
1.2.3.4,1.2.4.4 name.my.domain,name,n.my.domain,n,1.2.3.4,1.2.4.4
```

Answer (score -1):

I am under Windows 10, I can get the **saved** SSH key by issuing the following command:

`ssh-keygen -F sdf.org`

obtaining the following output

```
# Host sdf.org found: line 1
sdf.org,205.166.94.16 ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJJk3a190w/1TZkzVKORvz/kwyKmFY144lVeDFm80p17
```

With the following command I can get the **current** SSH key:

`ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 sdf.org`

obtaining the output

```
# sdf.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
sdf.org ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJJk3a190w/1TZkzVKORvz/kwyKmFY144lVeDFm80p17
```

I can visually compare the two values, to be sure the SSH key is correct.
I bet it can be done also in a batch file (but I do not know how)

Comment: The question was HOW to script it.

Comment: LOL so I failed, but was happy to share the methods to get current and stored SSH key, feel free to delete/edit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).